# get <li> element height excluding descendants

Tags: html, height, html-lists, element

Given:

`<li>I want this height
  <ul>
    <li>but not this height</li>
  </ul>
</li>`

I want to get the height of the first `<li>` element, excluding the descendant `<ul><li>...` content.

`offsetHeight`, `clientHeight`, `scrollHeight` etc. all give the height of the entire outer `<li>...</li>` element.

Comment: Are you using Vanilla JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract height of `LI` and `UL` separately and then subtract it to get the height of `LI` only.

Using `jQuery` library it can be done as,

```
var liHeight = $('#test > li').outerHeight(); // Get First Li Height

var liUlHeight = $('#test li > ul').outerHeight(); // Get Height of First UL inside Li

var onlyliHeight = liHeight - liUlHeight;

alert('Full LI Height='+liHeight+' -- UL Height='+liUlHeight+' -- Only LI Height='+onlyliHeight);
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/frqc6j7a/)

Using Vanilla JavaScript,

```
var liHeight = document.querySelector('#test > li').offsetHeight; // Get First Li Height

var liUlHeight = document.querySelector('#test li > ul').offsetHeight; //Get Height of First UL inside Li

var onlyliHeight = liHeight - liUlHeight;

alert('Full LI Height='+liHeight+' -- UL Height='+liUlHeight+' -- Only LI Height='+onlyliHeight);
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ga2sdk9b/)

> Output
>
> Full LI Height=42 -- UL Height=22 -- Only LI Height=20

Comment: Thanks, that would work. That said there could be many nested UL, LI items which would make it a bit more complex and possibly not as performant as one would like. Another option might be to hide the ```<ul>``` so it had no height, but I haven't tried that.